# Inserting and searching a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble with my BST. The BST which I am supposed to build has an implicit 'rank' in which the Nodes are sorted by. For instance, when inserting a new Node I am given a value to store in the Node and the rank in which to insert it. In other words the BST is supposed to store a sequence. My insert function appears to work but small bugs appear occasionally and the select function throws a NullPointerException when it should not.

[Node.java](https://pastebin.com/Lipdu7ta)

[RBST.java](https://pastebin.com/W0DE1knD)

[RBSTTest.java](https://pastebin.com/G2F0s81E)

```
public void insertNormal(int team, int rank)
{
    root = insertNormal(root, team, rank);
}

 /**
 * Insert the data team at position rank into node T. This is the normal
 * insert routine without any balancing.
 */
private Node insertNormal(Node T, int team, int rank)
{
    assert (rank >= 1 && rank <= T.getSize() + 1) : "rank should be between 1 and size of the tree <"
        + (T.getSize() + 1) + ">";

    if (T == null)
    {
        return new Node(team);
    }

    if (getRank(T) >= rank)
    {
        T.setLeft(insertNormal(T.getLeft(), team, rank));
    }
    else
    {
        T.setRight(insertNormal(T.getRight(), team, rank));
    }
    T.incSize();

    return T;
}


public Node select(int rank)
{
    return select(root, rank);
}

/**
 * The select method that returns the node in the tree at position rank.
 */
private Node select(Node T, int rank)
{
    if (T == null || getRank(T) == rank)
        return T;

    assert (rank >= 1 && rank <= T.getSize()) : "rank should be between 1 and size of the tree <" + T.getSize()
        + "> ";

    if (getRank(T) > rank)
        T = T.getLeft();
    else
        T = T.getRight();

    return select(T, rank);
}

public int getRank(Node T)
{
    return (T.getLeft() == null ? 1 : T.getLeft().getSize() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Probably this line `T.setRight(insertNormal(T.getRight(), team, rank));` should be in else condition.

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel Wow big oversight thank you but unfortunately still have the same issues. I'm more impressed that it's worked near as good as it has without the else.

Comment: It depends on the data you are inserting, if this condition `getRank(T) >= rank` is true, setLeft and setRight both will be called

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel Yeah it happened because I changed it from two return statements to setting T equal to a value and then just returning T. My select is still giving me a NullPointerException and it seems to have an issue if I insert a value at a rank which already has a value it appears to not insert the value or possibly overwrite the value.

Comment: Why is the condition to go left `>=` in the `insert` and `>` in the `select`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Because at the condition == in select we have found the rank we are looking for. In the binary search tree everything that is less than or equal to the root goes to the left of the root.

Comment: You should probably add the `getRank` method to your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Done

Comment: Can you add stacktrace? It should point you to the line number from where the NPE is being thrown?

Comment: @AnandMattikopp Sure, I have test functions which I am provided with to assure that the functions work as intended. I've traced it through execution using a debugger. The test function tries to print every element in the tree using the select function and the NPE appears when trying to print the 7th element. 

    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at RBSTTest.main(RBSTTest.java:107)`

When tracing the variables it shows the T has both a left and right Node (non-null) but when it returns to the calling function in RBSTTest it returns null.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Just describing your test wouldn't do. We don't know the order in which you insert items etc., and we don't know what the `getSize` and `incSize` methods do. We can't recreate it.

Comment: your ` T.getLeft().getSize() ` in `getRank` could be the culprit as `T.getLeft()` may return null.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I edited the post with the files as well

Comment: @HariUserX But wouldn't the ternary condition take care of that since I'm first checking `T.getLeft() == null` and returning 1 in that case, otherwise I return the size of the left plus 1.

Comment: Interestingly, the sources that you added do not have the assert statements that appear in your question. I'm pretty sure the asserts will fail. Try to think what the rank and size of the root's right child are.

Answer (score 0):

The binary search tree is constructed a bit strangely. Apparently you know the rank of the teams beforehand. In that case, you would normally store the rank with the team in the `Node`. Then you can easily retrieve the rank later. That way, you are also not forced to add the teams in order of their ranks.

Your current `getRank()` method currently does not actually retrieve the rank. Note that if you add teams in order of their rank now, you will get a very lob-side tree with the sub-tree always on the right side, with the left side always `null`. That is also likely where your faults come from: `getRank()` will always return 1.

Comment: Yeah we have always learned Binary search trees in a way that the value, rank, etc is stored within each Node. However this time it's implicit (I don't get to choose the implementation unfortunately). As far as the lob-sided tree goes I am aware of it as we are first to implement a insertNormal() function which just inserts the teams in-order by their rank (not their team number) then eventually I have to implement an insert() function which has a 1/(size of the tree + 1) chance that the currently inserted node will become the root. How would I find the rank of a Node then?

Comment: The size field in the Node is also strange. I assume that is supposed to give the number of nodes in the whole subtree? You would normally not keep track of that, because it requires going over the whole tree when moving some tree leaves to other places.

Comment: I assume this is a school assignment? I would create a new class with team and rank as members, and store that in the Node instead.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to hold the size of it's subtree, so this would be the entire tree for the root and only the nodes on the left side of the tree for the root's left node. Which is why I assume can be the only way to figure the rank but I'm not sure in an unbalanced tree.

Comment: Yeah it is a school assignment, unfortunately I've had several issues similar to this in this class. I think I may just do that or just add rank as a member in its own and go from there even though the instructions say "The Node class is fully implemented with all accessors and mutators necessary." >.<